# Angular 4+ ngClass Mix Expressions

Tags: angular, ng-class

I am trying to pass in 2 values to ngClass.

How do you do this:

```
[ngClass]="'cssprefix-' + var.value, {'newclass' : ifTrue}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could move the logic that describes what classes to add to controller's method:

```
// controller
getClasses(ifTrue: boolean, value: string) {
    const ret = {};
    ret['cssprefix-' + value] = true;
    ret['newclass'] = ifTrue;

    return ret;
} 

// in template
[ngClass]="getClasses(ifTrue, var.value)"
```

You could also bind to `class` attribute directly:

```
[class]="'cssprefix-' + var.value" [ngClass]="{'newclass' : ifTrue}"
```

Or use string interpolation:

```
class="{{ 'cssprefix-' + var.value }}" [ngClass]="{'newclass' : ifTrue}"
```

Answer (score 2):

Edit New Answer:
In my old answer ngClass was taking the "as c" "c" as literally the css class "c". This seems to work though.

```
<div [class]="'csspefix-' + cssSuffix.value" [ngClass]="{ 'newclass' : ifTrue}"></div>
```

Old Answer:
In my example I renamed `var` to `cssSuffix` because the parser didn't like the `var` keyword.

```
<div *ngIf="'csspefix-' + cssSuffix.value as c" [ngClass]="{ c: true, 'newclass' : ifTrue}"></div>
```

This was the only way I could get it to work becuase the parser didn't like "+" or "(" on the property side of the object expression in ngClass.

Answer (score 0):

`[ngClass]` takes an object and parse it for styles. So your two values will be passed inside an object as below and corresponding class in the left

```
[ngClass]="{'cssprefix-' + var.value: ! ifTrue, 'newclass' : ifTrue}"
```

Little More information:
You can also execute logical operator and other condition inside `[ngClass]`

```
[ngClass]="{'someCondClass': ifTrue && (somethingElse || anotherCondition)}"
```

Comment: this makes the assumption that the asker wants either one or the other

Comment: @Aniruddha Das Doesn't work - you get an error that it expected a : after fix-'

Comment: `: after` is a sudo class I think. Can you mention what is you trying to achieve. normally `[ngClass]` works in this way

Comment: @AniruddhaDas, RooksStrife is referring to a syntax error message not the sudo class.

Comment: Btw its called pseudo selector :)